# How to disable css transition for specific line of css?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hello I have a div that is set to a fixed height, and when you hover over it, it grows by a certain amount.

I also have it set so when you hover over the div, the background color changes as well.

Right now the hover transitions the height AND the background color. Is there any way to disable the transition for just the background color? The background color transitions with the height, it fades from black to white with the height change. I dont want the background color to fade.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="text">text text text</p>
    <p class="content">text text text text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.box:hover {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 40px;
}
```

[Here is the jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nhvuwu9z/1/)

Comment: If you don't want to transition _all_ properties that change, then don't use the `all` keyword, but specify the properties by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the question but is this what you want?

```
.box {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.10s ease;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.10s ease;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.10s ease;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.10s ease;
    transition: max-height 0.10s ease;
}
```

Comment: The background color transitions with the height, it fades from black to white with the height change. I dont want the background color to fade

Comment: Yes, what i have provided doesn't have that fade effect, but it still changes colour. if you don't want it to change colour then just add the same colour to the box and box hover.

Comment: i didnt notice you changed "all" to "max-height". that was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question exactly. Is it that you want the box to change its height but not color? If yes, you just need to remove the 'background-color' attribute from '.box:hover'
Just change the code to this

```
.box:hover {
    height: 300px;
    //background-color: #fff;
}
```

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/nhvuwu9z/16/

Comment: The background color transitions with the height, it fades from black to white with the height change. I dont want the background color to fade.

Comment: i will want the background color to change though! i just dont want the change of color to fade out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to add a class to the div that will keep the background white.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.box').one("mouseover", function() {
        $('.box').addClass('box_white');
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.box:hover {
    height: 300px;
   background-color: #fff;
    top: 40px;
}
.box_white {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <p class="text">text text text</p>
    <p class="content">text text text text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this works but the solution that AJ Riley provided was alot easier and worked the same. Thanks though! i gave you an upvote